# Interceptors in ejb 3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

What is the name of the annotations used to declare an interceptor and used to bind an interceptor with a bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotation that is used to bind interceptor to bean or to method is [javax.interceptor.Interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptors.html). When bean itself implement interceptor methods, then Interceptors can be used to bind additional interceptors. Methods with following annotations can be implemented in separate interceptor class or in bean/entity itself.

Annotation to use to declare method as intercepting method is:

- [javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/interceptor/AroundInvoke.html)

As an addition there is following lifecycle callback interceptors for both stateless and stateful session beans:

- [javax.annotation.PreDestroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html)
- [javax.annotation.PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

And finally exclusively for stateful beans following are provided:

- [javax.ejb.PostActivate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/PostActivate.html)
- [javax.ejb.PrePassivate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/PrePassivate.html)

For entities following annotations are available to design method as one that is receiving lifecycle callbacks:

- [javax.persistence.PostLoad](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html)
- [javax.persistence.PrePersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html)
- [javax.persistence.PostPersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PostPersist.html)
- [javax.persistence.PreUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html)
- [javax.persistence.PostUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html)
- [javax.persistence.PreRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PreRemove.html)
- [javax.persistence.PostRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PostRemove.html)

Comment: You can have both @Interceptors and interceptor methods defined on the bean class.

Comment: That is true of course, my wording is bit misleading. And additionally also default interceptors in deployment descriptors and interceptors derived from superclasses.